# How to add 4 hours in a format cells as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and fit year,month and day

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to add 4 hours in a format cells as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and fit year,month and day.

Example below.[image]

Comment: Is this Excel or LibreCalc? Never Seen that toolbar in Excel 2010

Comment: Or `Calc` from Open office?

Comment: Siddhart Rout, These are my Add-In tests.

Comment: Ah no Wonder! I see! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Simple formula should do `=A1+"04:00:00"`

Answer (score 6):

Write a formula:

```
=A1+1/6
```

This will add 4 hours (1/6 of day).

Comment: Yep, it's kind of a well-kept secret that time values are stored as a floating-point days and fractions thereof.